# Diverse sfumature di significato di "tacciare" e "accusare"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I due verbi afferiscono allo stesso significato e reggono anche la stessa preposizione (di). *Tacciare* è naturalmente meno frequente e più ricercato.

Esistono contesti/esempi in cui i due verbi non possano essere scambiati perché non equivalenti?

Se sì, dove, nella storia ed etimologia, si trova la radice della differenza?

Comment: Secondo me una differenza c'è: il verbo "_tacciare_" veicola anche un senso di infamia che il verbo "_accusare_" non ha. Il primo comporta un giudizio morale, il secondo è più neutro. In un'aula di tribunale il pubblico ministero non potrebbe tacciare l'imputato di un reato, ma accusarlo sì.

Comment: _Tacciare_ significa letteralmente _mettere una tacca_. L'idea è quindi quella di esporre al pubblico ludibrio, infangare, sporcare la reputazione. È però possibile che molti usino il verbo pensando erroneamente che equivalga a _mettere a tacere, tacitare_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'etimolgia dei due termini è molto diversa ma il significato attuale è simile nel senso di attribuire una colpa o una responsabilità a qualcuno. Accusare a differenza di tacciare è il termine che viene usato in ambito legale, inoltre accusare ha altri significati : Manifestare e palesare. ( vedi sotto).

**[Tacciare:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tacciare/)**

> - Accusare, imputare di una colpa o di un vizio (si intende, in genere, d’imputazione non giudiziale): lo tacciarono a torto di tradimento; era tacciato di essere una spia.

[Tacciare etimologia:](http://www.etimo.it/?term=taccia)

> - da tacia o tacca  che, per l'influsso francese di *tache*, ha assunto il significato di macchia in senso metaforico ( pecca, colpa o accusa) da cui *tacciare*.

**[Accusare:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/Accusare/)**

> - Attribuire una colpa, muovere un’accusa: nelle note informative, il direttore lo accusava di eccessiva negligenza; *in partic., chiamare una persona davanti ai giudici per rispondere di un fatto previsto dalla legge come reato*: a. qualcuno d’aver rubato, di aver ucciso; fu accusato di omicidio, di furto, di peculato.
> - Manifestare, dichiarare: a. un disturbo, un dolore al piede, ecc.; a. il ricevimento di una lettera (nell’uso burocr., a. ricevuta); per estens., a. il colpo, lasciare chiaramente intendere di essere stato colpito (in senso proprio o, più spesso, fig.). Con accezione partic., a. i proprî peccati, dichiararli in confessione.

[Accusare etimologia](http://www.etimo.it/?term=Accusare&find=Cerca):

> - da causa o cagione. Accagionare ossia attribuire ad altri la cagione, la colpa.

Answer (score 2):

come già scritto, "tacciare" non può sostituire "accusare" in ambito legale. Nel linguaggio comune io sento una leggera differenza di significato: se taccio qualcuno può esserci una sfumatura scherzosa, mentre se lo accuso no.

Comment: Anche nel significato “serio” c'è una differenza; a una persona potrei dire “ti accuso di furto”, ma non “ti taccio di ladro”. Secondo me *tacciare* è sempre indiretto (a meno che non sia scherzoso).